# ternary operator to variable in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I have a ternary operator test in my angularJS code to determinate which variable to use on a repeat block, but this test is being done many times inside it and I think this is dumb. Is there a way to store the expression result in a variable and use it instead of repeating the expression?

The code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="meta in metas">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
        {{meta.admMetNome}} <span class="pull-right">{{meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios['total'].qtd}} / {{meta.admMetValor}}</span>
        <md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="{{(meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios['total'].qtd) * 100 / meta.admMetValor}}"></md-progress-linear>
        {{(meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios['total'].qtd) * 100 / meta.admMetValor | number:2}}% - Prazo: de {{meta.admMetInicio | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} a {{meta.admMetFim | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Would be a good use case for a directive or component. Would take the business logic out of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in your controller should do the trick(assuming 'usuarios' is a scoped var). But like @charlietfl suggested would be a good opportunity for a directive.

```js
$scope.assignValue = function(meta) {
  return (meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId) ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios.total.qtd * (100 / meta.admMetValor);
};
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="meta in metas">
  <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">
    {{meta.admMetNome}} <span class="pull-right">{{meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios['total'].qtd}} / {{meta.admMetValor}}</span>
    <md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="assignValue(meta)">
    </md-progress-linear>
    {{(meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId ? usuarios[meta.pagCidadesPagCid[0].pagCidId].qtd : usuarios['total'].qtd) * 100 / meta.admMetValor | number:2}}% - Prazo: de {{meta.admMetInicio | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} a {{meta.admMetFim | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In controller object or in `$scope` create a function with a parameter to pass your `meta` in it. Like `getValue(meta)`. And simply `return` your ternary operator in it. Then just use this function in the expression: `value={{$ctrl.getValue(meta)}}`.